# Get data return php oop

Tags: php

getclass.php

```
  public $set;

  //dont need to care here the code is right , here is where it final result
  default;
  $this->actual_device = "desktop";
  echo $this->issetValueNull($this->actual_device);


  public function issetValueNull($mixed)
  {
  $this->set = $mixed;
  }
```

getdata.php

```
require_once "getclass.php";

$check_detect_device = new detect_device();

if($check_detect_device->issetValueNull->set1 = "desktop"){
  "<script>console.log('desktop');</script>";
}
```

i need to get the data from getclass.php to getdata.php and check the final result at getdata.php , some like below;

```
//this data return from getclass.php
if(isset($_GET['desktop'])){
"<script>console.log('desktop');</script>";
}
```

but i dont know how to return the data from getclass , can any one give me some advice ?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure is this what you are trying to do, but check my example:

```
<?php

class getClass
{
    public $actualDevice;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->actualDevice = "desktop";
    }

    public function setActualDevice($actualDevice)
    {
        $this->actualDevice = $actualDevice;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getActualDevice()
    {
        return $this->actualDevice;
    }

    public function issetActualDevice()
    {
        return isset($this->actualDevice);
    }
}

class getData
{
    public $getClass;

    public function __construct(getClass $getClass)
    {
        $this->getClass = $getClass;
    }

    public function checkDetectDevice($device)
    {
        if ($this->getClass->getActualDevice() == $device) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

$getClass = new getClass();
$getData = new getData($getClass);

if ($getData->checkDetectDevice($_GET['desktop'])) {
    echo "<script>console.log('desktop');</script>";
}
```

Comment: thank for helping , the data in getclass is $this->actual_device = "desktop";